# Trying to create fire - Settings disappear

Tags: interface

I am trying to create my first fire following a tutorial, as to be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-zK7Bu8cAI&t=?
And now I want to click on the right side to change from domain to flow but for any reason when I do that all settings disappear together with my fire and I would have to restart all over if I wouldn't be able to hit ctrl+Z to get everything back again.

Anybody got a solution?

Thanks for the attention. 
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "to change from domain to flow"? When you have fire simulation there are 2 objects, domain (a cube) and flow (one which emits fire). Settings in the Properties editor are shown only for active object, so as domain is active on your screenshot its options are shown.  So please clarify what settings disappear and when.

Comment: You see in the right menu these 4 buttons, none, domain, flow, collision. When I click on flow all marked settings disappear, smoke adaptive domain and everything inside, smoke high resolution and there is no fire to animate.

Comment: You aren't expected to press on Flow settings with domain selected. Domain must be remaining domain for the fire sim, flow object must be set to Flow. As above, there should be 2 objects, one domain and one flow object, flow emits fire, domain contains it. If you change these settings for only one object there won't be any simulation obviously

Comment: Yep, I got it, credits to me for not finding out myself. Thanks for the sip of reality and fresh look onto the work. And on we go. xD